# AngularJS: Lexer Error, single quote

Tags: angularjs

I am expriencing issue when I have single quote in string. This string comes out of database, so I can not change it manually. I have tried to escape single qoute with \' in Somefilter functionality but I think app breaks before reaching filter.

```
popup="content: '{{ 'Some string ' and something more' | Somefilter }}', variation: 'inverted', size: 'small'"
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character
```

Any ideas more?

Comment: Escape is `\'`not '\, did you try: `'Some string \' and something more' | Somefilter`?

Comment: There was a typo in my question.